# Troubleshooting "Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\FilterManager' not found"

Tags: symfony

How can I solve the error.

> Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\FilterManager' not found

Comment: Did you use [autoloader](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/tools/autoloader.html) to load this class? Post your code, it would be easier to find source of the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Class 'AppBundle\AppBundle' not found in AppKernel.php after install DoctrineFixturesBundle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30028204/fatal-error-class-appbundle-appbundle-not-found-in-appkernel-php-after-instal)