# Fatal error: Class 'AppBundle\AppBundle' not found in AppKernel.php after install DoctrineFixturesBundle

Tags: symfony

I try install DoctrineFixturesBundle in symfony 2.6.6 using this [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html). However, I get:

> Fatal error: Class 'AppBundle\AppBundle' not found

If I remove `AppBundle\AppBundle` from `AppKernel.php`, I have the same problem with another bundle. I installed Symfony via the Symfony installer and my `composer.json` was empty before I added:

```
{
    "require": {
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "2.2.*"
    }
}
```

Maybe this is a part of the problem?

Comment: What is `AppBundle\AppBundle`? Why did you put it in `composer.json`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add [autoloading configuration](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload) to your `composer.json`.

Comment: btw, the composer.json should not be empty after installation. What command did you run?

Comment: I installed symfony via symfony installer,without composer.I add  this code  in composer.json and download composer                                             {
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/", "SymfonyStandard": "app/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "2.2.*",
     
    }
}
and execude next command  php composer.phar update doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle