# Symfony 2 issue

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I am trying to develop an application using Symfony2 php framework. I am getting below error while I am trying to update composer.

```
Fatal error: Class 'AppBundle\AppBundle' not found in D:\php\htdocs\my_project\app\A
ppKernel.php on line 21
Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handl
ing the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception


  [RuntimeException]
  An error occurred when executing the ""cache:clear --no-warmup"" command.


update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock]
 [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-
progress] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader]
 [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [packages1] ... [p
ackagesN]
```

Here is my `composer.json` file

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "": "src/",
            "SymfonyStandard\\": "app/SymfonyStandard/"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.9",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.7.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3,<2.5",
        "doctrine/dbal": "<2.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~4.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.2",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "SymfonyStandard\\Composer::hookRootPackageInstall"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.7-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Could anyone help me to get rid of this error ?? Thanks

Comment: In your `app/AppKernel` find a line containing `new AppBundle\AppBundle....()`. Comment that out and try again. If it works, it means you're trying to import a bundle which doesn't exist.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Class 'AppBundle\AppBundle' not found in AppKernel.php after install DoctrineFixturesBundle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30028204/fatal-error-class-appbundle-appbundle-not-found-in-appkernel-php-after-instal)